# srand(time(NULL)) not giving strings anymore

Tags: c++

As a beginner in programming I can not find why srand would just not change the string anymore.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
int v[100], i, p, n,

srand(time(NULL));
cout<<"Numbers of numbers: "; cin>>n; cout<<endl;

for(i=0; i<=n-1; i++)
v[i]=rand()%100;

cout<<"Numbers: "<<endl;
for(i=0; i<=n-1; i++)
    cout<<v[i]<<" ";

for(i=0; i<=(n-1)/2; i++){
p=v[i];
v[i]=v[n-(i+1)];
v[n-(i+1)]=p;
}

cout<<"Reversed numbers: "<<endl;
for(i=0; i<=n-1; i++)
    cout<<v[i]<<" ";

return 0;
}
```

Tried rebuilding it, rewriting it from 1, and such. Even if it did work perfectly before it's just one type of bug that yeah, simply won't work.

Edit: Weird because I copy pasted the beginning and it worked with that... I guess it was my mistake. Not paying enough attention T_T

Comment: What string are you talking about?

Comment: What change did you do for it to stop working?

Comment: `srand` does not modify a string. `srand` is used to seed an RNG.

Comment: Is the program generating the same array of numbers all the time (i.e. whenever you start it) or just if you start it a couple of times e.g. in a script?

Comment: It compiles/runs fine for me using g++. It does indeed produce the same numbers every time which is possibly the problem here?

Comment: Example: Start: 0 1 2 3 swtches them to 3 2 1 0, closing the program.
Start 2: 0 1 2 3 

So it's supposed to make them random, I copied the start of it WITHOUT the reversing of the numbers and it works, but it STOPS working even if it is supposed to

Codeblocks with gnu compiler and whatever. I've seen kind of ghost bugs before but they usually fixed themselves after writing the same thing and building it again

Comment: If you run the program once, wait a couple of seconds, and run it again, will it produce the exact same sequence then too?

Comment: Yep. Tried at interval of minutes and even after rewriting it completely =))

Other programs using the same method to allocate them work fine and as said, I copy pasted the first half of it and it worked fine, but I don't see how it won't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you enable more warnings you will see something like

```
program.cpp:11:1: warning: unused variable 'srand' [-Wunused-variable]
srand(time(NULL));
^
```

The reason can be seen on the previous line: It ends in a *comma*

```
int v[100], i, p, n,
// Note comma here ^
```

So what the code is doing is declaring a *variable* named `srand`, and not calling a *function* called `srand`.

Take this as a lesson to *always* build with extra warnings enabled. Enabling more warnings made this problem very obvious, but it can also give hints about cases of undefined behavior.